# How to restore purchases using MKStoreKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My app was rejected from apple because it does not have a restore button, but I am using MKStoreKit, so if the app is purchased and the the device is wiped and the user click my purchase button again, it does re-download and 'restore' the app.

So, can someone explain what they are asking me to do?  I thought MKStoreKit handled this for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just call `restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete`

```
#import "MKStoreManager.h"

-(void)restorePreviousPurchase{
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager]restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete:^{NSLog(@"RESTORED PREVIOUS PURCHASE");} onError:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your app you need to add a restore button, which will allow the user to restore there previous purchases.

`MKStoreKit` does all this, but you will need to add the button to `UI` your self.
Then you can call the `restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete:onError:` method on `MKStoreManager`

Comment: Yes, but how do I tell if it should be restored or not?  Problem is this, my App has no purchasable add-ons.  Meaning, you download it for free, and then if you want the full version, you purchase it via in-app purchase.  All works great, even if you wipe and re-purchase.  However, Apple wants me to add a restore... so how do I know if I need to restore, or purchase?  Does this make sense?

Comment: You just need to put that button to be there always. You don't have to know if the app needs restore, there's no way to tell unless you try to re-purchase. User is the one who knows if he ever purchased anything with your app. Simply put that button and use MKStoreKit's api for restore and Apple will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction) RestoreCompletedTransactions:(id)sender
{
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Not sure about the button though, I guess mine is always displayed.

Comment: +one for non-MKStoreKit